# PL / SQL Function to return varchar2 / numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, rowtype

I have this PL / SQL function that accepts the name of a student (f_name). The function then displays all of the information for the given student from a premade table called students. The table contains 5 columns, 2 number type, and 3 varchar2 type. If the name isn't found in the table an error message is returned. My code so far is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION studentName(
    f_name IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN
IS
  v_test students%rowtype;
  CURSOR c1
  IS
    SELECT * FROM students WHERE first_name = f_name;
BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
  FETCH c1 INTO v_test;
  IF c1%notfound THEN
    v_test := NULL;
  END IF;
CLOSE c1;
RETURN v_test;
END;
```

I keep getting:

> PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

I believe from my initial return varchar2 statement. How do I allow the return to accept both varchar2 type and number type?

Comment: the type of v_test that you return `students%rowtype;` conflicts with your return type of `varchar2`. In fact to accept the return you´d need to, change the return type to `students%rowtype`

Comment: `students%rowtype` is a type of *one variable*, what is the problem?

Comment: nevermind fixed thanks guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> RETURN varchar2

You need to return the **rowtype**, but you are returning a **scalar**. `VARCHAR2` cannot hold a row, it can hold only a string value.

Modify it to:

```
RETURN students%rowtype;
```

**Demo** using standard EMP table:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION studentName(
  2      f_name IN VARCHAR2)
  3    RETURN emp%rowtype
  4  IS
  5    v_test emp%rowtype;
  6    CURSOR c1
  7    IS
  8      SELECT * FROM emp WHERE ename = f_name;
  9  BEGIN
 10    OPEN c1;
 11    FETCH c1 INTO v_test;
 12    IF c1%notfound THEN
 13      v_test := NULL;
 14    END IF;
 15  CLOSE c1;
 16  RETURN v_test;
 17  END;
 18  /

Function created.

SQL> sho err
No errors.
```

**NOTE** : `%ROWTYPE` implies **PL/SQL record type** and PL/SQL types are not known to **SQL**. So you won't be able to use the function directly in plain SQL. You need to use **SQL object type**. Else you will get:

> ORA-06553: PLS-801: internal error [55018]

**Workaround to use it in SQL:**

```
SQL> create or replace
  2    type student_obj_type
  3      as object(
  4                student_id number,
  5                stu_name varchar2(20),
  6                dept varchar2(20)
  7               )
  8  /

Type created.
```

Use **student_obj_type** instead of **students%rowtype** to use the function in **SQL**.

Comment: I added another piece of information, hope it would help.